# flask-sqlalchemy select count()

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

i have query like this

```
query = Notification.query(db.func.count(Notification.id))
query = query.filter(Notification.read == False)
query = query.filter(Notification.id == recv_id)
return query.all()
```

and i got error like this

> query = Notification.query(db.func.count(Notification.id))
>   TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable

please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first line raises the error. `query` is an instance of BaseQuery and its not callable.

What you are trying to do is similar to:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a_obj = A()
print a_obj()
```

You can't call an instance.

You should call some method on the instance.

Not sure why you require the first line in your code.

You can do something like:

```
Notification.query.filter(Notification.read == False)
```

Comment: yes, thank you for mention it :) but i still got error at this line `query = Notification.query(db.func.count(Notification.id)) maybe the db.func.count()`

Comment: This is the line which gives the error. What have you changed? You can't do `query(db.func.count())`. You will have to use `query.filter()` or some other method on `query`. You are trying to use `query` itself as a method which you can't do because it is an instance.

Comment: now i understand about calling an instance, i have another solutions for this problem, i use paginate() to get total count from query result. like this `query.paginate(1, per_page=10, error_out=True)` it works for me thanks :) by the way i'am beginner in python